# External Testing is missing from App Store Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to send my app to External TestFlight testers. All the [tutorials](https://messapps.com/allcategories/development/intro-testflight-external-testing/) mention that I should be able to add external testers via an External Testing tab on the left hand side. I don't see this option.

I tried filling in all the details in "Test Information" but I still don't see the section.

How do I see the External Testers section for my app?

Answer (score 21):

I resolved this by creating an Internal Testing group first. After doing this, I was able to see the plus sign near the External Testing header on the left hand side.

Note: There's also a chance that I didn't need to create this group, and simply waiting 15-30 minutes caused it to appear.

Comment: No, waiting isn't the solution. I waited and nothing appeared, it appeared right after I added an Internal Testing group.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth mentioning that if you don't have any available build on the app, the external testing section will be hidden.

Even when you had external testers, and somehow all builds expire/are marked as invalid binary, the section will be hidden (leaving all groups intact, you just don't see it).

If this was the case, simply uploading a new build would fix the issue.